# Binding a function that is to be used inside a Function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, binding, constructor, callback

I intend to create a "preprocessual" function that is invoked right before a callback is invoked. In other words, invoking a callback should follow the pattern: preprocessual function -> callback. In order to "insert" such a preprocessual function, I could simply create a closure, rewrite the callback inside the closure so that the preprocessual function gets invoked, then at the end of that rewritten callback, invoke the original callback.

```
var end = function(init) {
    /*
        In here, init is processed.
        Init contains multiple callbacks.
        One callback is chosen to be invoked.
    */
    init.callback();
};

var closure = function(init) {
    var old = init.callback;
    init.callback = function() {
        /*
            Do the preprocessual stuff
        */
        console.log("The preprocessual functionality has now taken place.");
        return old.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };

    return end.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};

closure({
    /*among other properties*/
    callback: function() {
        console.log("The preprocessual callback must have been invoked when 'end' invokes me.");
    }
});
```

However, I have multiple callbacks, while I have only one preprocessual function. Each invocation of those callbacks should be preceded by an invocation of the same preprocessual function. In order to not have to write a preprocessual callback for each separate possible callback, I made a loop in the closure, that assigns the variable `old` to the next callback, then rewrote the callback using the Function constructor.

Everything still works. However, I am no longer able to use non global variables in my callback function that it could originally access. The following crashes, claiming that `variable` is not defined (as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

```
(function() {
    var end = function(init) {
        /*
            In here, init is processed.
            Init contains multiple callbacks.
            One callback is chosen to be invoked.
        */
        init.callback();
    };

    var closure = function(init) {
        var old = init.callback;
        init.callback = new Function(
            "\
                /*\
                    Do the preprocessual stuff\
                */\
                console.log(\"The preprocessual functionality has now taken place.\");\
                return " + old + ".apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));\
            "
        );

        return end.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };

    var variable = "value";

    closure({
        /*among other properties*/
        callback: function() {
            console.log("The preprocessual callback must have been invoked when 'end' invokes me.");
            console.log(variable);
        }
    });
})();
```

So then I thought, let's try to `bind` the variables I need in my callback to the callback function. I then encountered a very strange problem. For some reason binding a scope/parameters to the callback function (with which the Function constructor has little to do), results in strange errors. A small example of such an error:

**This works**

```
var callback = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
};

callback = new Function(
    "\
    return " + callback + ".apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));\
    "
);

callback(1, 2, 3);
```

**This does not work**

```
var callback = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
}.bind(this);

callback = new Function(
    "\
    return " + callback + ".apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));\
    "
);

callback(1, 2, 3);
```

It does not matter if I assign the callback to another variable, such as `old`, in between and use `old` in the Function constructor and it doesn't matter if I use a completely different bound function inside the Function constructor, either. Any bound function (whether referenced to with a variable or not) gives me the error: "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list".

**In fact, even this fails**

```
callback = new Function(
    "\
    return " + (function() {}.bind(this)) + ".apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));\
    "
);

callback(1, 2, 3);
```

And I fail to figure out why this is the case. Useful help would be appreciated.

As requested, the actual use case:

```
var
    ajax = function(init) {
        for (var i = 0, callbacks = ["success", "error"]; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            if (init.hasOwnProperty(callbacks[i] + "Callback")) {
                init[callbacks[i] + "Callback"] = new Function("responseText",
                    "\
                    /*\
                        Preprocessual callback takes place here (among other things, messages from the server are inserted in the document)\ 
                    */\
                    \
                    return " + init[callbacks[i] + "Callback"] + ".apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));\
                    "
                );
            }
        }

        // This is the actual ajax function, which can operate independently of the project (in contrary, the preprocessual callback needs to know about where to insert messages in the document)
        return cregora.ajax.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
;

(function() {
    // some scope with variables..

    ajax({
        url: "url",
        callbackThis: this,
        successCallback: function(responseText) {
            console.log("I need some variables available in this scope");
        },
        errorCallback: function() {
            console.log("I need some variables available in this scope");
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Can you please explain the step that made you go from 'normal' function to using the Function constructor + the function body as a string?

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme Yes, I have multiple callbacks in the init object, which all must be preceded by the same preprocessual callback. I don't intend to write 99% equal code for each one of them, as the only difference would be the name of the original callback to be invoked at the end of the rewritten callback. I left out the loop in the example though.

Comment: That's where I am having trouble understanding you. They all need the same wrapper on different callbacks. Such a thing is definitely possible without using `new Function`. That's why I am more curious about that part of the question. It seems, if we solve that, we solve your issue. So maybe you can also link to the specific code that made that change necessary and I may be able to point out how to change it.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme See my edit at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected, you were actually overcomplicating the issue a little bit.
Instead of using the function constructor, you can build a higher order function that returns an appropriate handler and automatically wraps the function (like your preprocessors).

```
var callbackWrapper = function (callback) {
    // Returns new anonymous function that acts as the handler
    return function responseHandler (responseText) {
        // Do your pre-processing
        console.log(responseText);
        callback.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };
};

var ajax = function(init) {
    for (var i = 0, callbacks = ["success", "error"]; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
        var callbackName = callbacks[i] + "Callback";
        if (init.hasOwnProperty(callbackName)) {
            var callback = init[callbackName];
            init[callbackName] = callbackWrapper(callback);
        }
    }

    // This is the actual ajax function, which can operate in independent of the project (for example, the preprocessual callback needs to know about where to insert messages in the document)
    return cregora.ajax.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};


(function() {
    // some scope with variables..

    ajax({
        url: "url",
        callbackThis: this,
        successCallback: function(responseText) {
            console.log("I need some variables available in this scope");
        },
        errorCallback: function() {
            console.log("I need some variables available in this scope");
        }
    });
})();
```

If you care, you can even change the callbackWrapper to use exactly the same preProcessor function every time:

```
var callbackWrapper = (function createCallbackWrapper () {
    var preProcessor = function (responseText) {
        console.log(responseText);
    };

    return function callbackWrapper (callback) {
        // Returns new anonymous function that acts as the handler
        return function responseHandler (responseText) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            preProcessor.apply(this, args);
            callback.apply(this, args);
        };
    };
})();
```

Now you will have no problems at all with binding the original callback functions.

A little more explanation on the issue:

When you use `fn + ".apply(...)"`, JS will turn the original function into a string. That is why you will have a hard time accessing closure variables, or anything else that is not in either your `var closure` function scope or the global scope.

It also fails in your case because after calling `.bind` on a function, its string representation turns into `"function () { [native code] }"`.
That is of course not a valid function body and will give you lots of trouble.

That conversion to a string is the actual problem, and it is one that is not easily solved. For that reason, using `new Function` is almost never the proper solution, and once you found yourself using it, you should assume you made a mistake in your reasoning. If you didn't, and `new Function` is indeed the only solution, you'd know.

Comment: I feel really silly for not seeing how basic the solution is. Thank you for the explanation regarding the string conversion .